# How to remove extra empty xticks from a pandas plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib. My pandas table has 4 columns, and I expect 4 xticklabels in the plot. However, the resulting graph has 7 xticklabels. This wouldn't be a problem, but I later need to update the label characteristics, and it's a challenge because I was expecting to use len(ax.get_xticklabels()) to get the number and expecting it to be 4 (the number of columns)

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = {'T1': [15, 22], 'T2': [25, 40], 'T3': [30, 15], 'T4': [12, 19]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=['A', 'B'])
print(df)
ax = df.T.plot(figsize=(7, 6))
plt.show()
print('xticks: {}'.format(ax.get_xticklabels()))
print('num xticks: {}'.format(len(ax.get_xticklabels())))
```

Output:
xticks: [Text(-0.5, 0, ''), Text(0.0, 0, 'T1'), Text(0.5, 0, ''), Text(1.0, 0, 'T2'), Text(1.5, 0, ''), Text(2.0, 0, 'T3'), Text(2.5, 0, ''), Text(3.0, 0, 'T4'), Text(3.5, 0, '')]

num xticks: 9

The resulting plot

[image: The resulting plot]

Comment: It's automatically setting the ticks (see https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/auto_ticks.html). If you want ticks at specific points you need `ax.set_xticks` and `ax.set_xlabels` (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matplotlib/matplotlib_setting_ticks_and_tick_labels.htm)

Comment: `ax = df.T.plot(figsize=(7, 6), xticks=range(len(df.columns)))` is all you require.

Comment: It's better to change the the dataframe and plot separately: `df = df.T` and `ax = df.plot(figsize=(7, 6), xticks=range(len(df.index)))`. [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoRGg.png)

Comment: McKinney.  Perfect, thanks.